# refer .js in AngularJS service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

In my angular environment I have below files.
app/scripts/constants.js

```
myApp.constant('constants', {
    errorMessages: {
        serverUnavailable: 'The server is not available at the moment, please try again later.'
    },
.
.
.
```

app/scripts/services/user.js

```
myApp.factory('MyHttpInterceptor', ['$q', '$injector', '$location', '$rootScope'
    function($q, $injector, $location, $rootScope) {
        .
        .
        .
    }
]);
```

I want to refer the 'serverUnavailable' defined in constants.js into user.js, for that, I have added constants.js as 'constants' at the end as shown below but it results in an error 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token function'.

app/scripts/services/user.js

```
myApp.factory('MyHttpInterceptor', ['$q', '$injector', '$location', '$rootScope', 'constants'
    function($q, $injector, $location, $rootScope, constants) {
        var v = constants.errorMessages.serverUnavailable;
```

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Updated the question with error detail.

Comment: Is it a typo that you don't have a comma after 'constants' and before function?

Comment: You caught it! That was the problem, it works now.

Comment: Great, would you kindly accept the answer if it helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a comma after 'constants' and before function.